# How to change image when checkbox checked

Tags: java, android, android-checkbox

i have this floating image called back in my service
MyService.java

```
    back = new ImageView(this);
    back.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.quick_launch_pressed_pink);
    back.setImageResource(R.drawable.back);
```

i want to change the ImageResource by calling MyService on another class, but my application force closed. here is my code on MainActivity.java

```
    public void addListenerOnCb() {

    chb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb);
    final MyService ms = new MyService();
    chb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //is chkIos checked?
            if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                ms.back.setImageResource(R.drawable.home);
            }

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Post the error too.

Comment: @AshwinMothilal i got E.AndroidRuntime: at f.myapp.Mainactivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:57)

Comment: That's not enough. We need full exception preferrably, and posted in question, not in a comment.

Comment: `final MyService ms = new MyService()` - You cannot instantiate a `Service` like that. It wouldn't the the same `Service` instance anyway.

Comment: so, how should i call the back.setImageResource(R.drawable.back); on another class?

Comment: i got an error to after using OnCheckedChangeListener,so the problem is on final MyService ms = new MyService();

Comment: Post the error by editing the question?

Comment: how do i get the error? i only get E.AndroidRuntime: at f.myapp.Mainactivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:57) from logcat

Answer (score 0):

add two different images for checked & unchecked in drawable
create xml file checkbox_selected.xml in your drawable folder

**checkbox_selected.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/remember_me_selected" />
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/remember_me_selected" />
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@drawable/remember_me_selected" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/remember_me" />
</selector>
```

**ImageView in url xml code**

```
       <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/remember_checkbox_img"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/checkbox_selected" />
```

Answer (score 0):

use this for CheckBox

```
    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                            if(b)
                           {
              // do something
                            }
                            else
                             {
                          // do another something
                               }
                        }
                    });
```